# python sqlite3 IF EXIST() ELSE not working

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to check

If a row with specific condition exists: **update it**

Else: **insert it**

using python sqlite3 library

Here is my code:

```
DbCursor.execute(
    "BEGIN TRANSACTION "
    "IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Cart WHERE UID = ? AND Status = 'open') "
    "   BEGIN"
    "       UPDATE Cart SET Price = Price + ?, Products = Products || ?, Expire = 10*60"
    "   END "
    "ELSE"
    "   BEGIN"
    "       INSERT INTO Cart(UID, Products, Price, Status, Expire) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, 10*60)"
    "   END "
    "END TRANSACTION;", (uid, price, f"{product_id},", uid, f"{product_id},", price, 'open')
)
database.commit()
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "EXISTS": syntax error
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Check for query validity by plainly running the query with a db client.

Comment: SQLite does not support IF..ELSE.. structures.

Comment: so what can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: do the if structure in python

Comment: Would [upsert in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) help you ? *UPSERT is a special syntax addition to INSERT that causes the INSERT to behave as an UPDATE or a no-op if the INSERT would violate a uniqueness constraint.*

Comment: @nbk yeah i was doing that :(. i jast wanted to do it simply in one query

Comment: @HadiH2o sqlite is made to be small so that complicated sql isn't really wanted the but on conflct Update will do the trick if you have a column that is unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came to the conclusion that there is no such thing as IF EXIST () in sqlite.

That's why I decided to do this operation in the Python way.

Here is the code :

```
open_cart = DbCursor.execute("SELECT ID FROM Cart WHERE UID = ? AND Status = 'open';", [uid]).fetchone()
if open_cart:
    DbCursor.execute(
        "UPDATE Cart SET Price = Price + ?, Products = Products || ?, Expire = 10*60 WHERE UID = ?;",
        [price, f"{product_id},", uid]
   )

else:
    DbCursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO Cart(UID, Products, Price, Status, Expire) VALUES(?, ?, ?, 'open', 10*60)",
        [uid, f"{product_id},", price]
)
database.commit()
```